# What Design pattern for keeping data partly in persistent storage (SQL) and Partly in RAM (memory)?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, design-patterns, memory

I am projecting an app with C++ and Qt.
I have **frequently needed** data in Class     **Object** and **rarely neded** data in Class **ObjectExtended**.
Every **Object** is associated with **ObjectExtended**.

Example:

```
 Class Object 
 {
     string importantData; //we need that very often
     int id;
 }

 Class ObjectExtended
 {
     date dateCreated; //meta info, we need this rarely
     int assosiatedObjectId; //to know to which Object this extended data relates
 }
```

I have the list of objects  `list<Object>` and `list<ObjectExtended>`

What I want is to keep list in RAM (memory) and keep list in ROM (local storage, for example SQL). 
It is needed to save memory. I already keep data in SQL to save application state and data.

The problem which I may face is that my data can change and I will have to rewrite tonns of code if I separate data for **Object** and **ObjectExtended**.

Is there some design pattern which suits the best for my issue?

Comment: When you say "my data can change", you mean it can change at run-time, or you mean that the data schema changes (design time)?

Comment: Do you mean "ROM", as in Read-Only-Memory? Or are you looking to save ObjectExtended in persistent storage, such as a database or file system?

Comment: I mean that I can for example that I can move some members from **ObjectExtended** to **Object** and vice-versa, not in runtime, but in code (change architecture of app, for example I will add methods  in **Object** whith needs new data from **ObjectExtended** and I will have to move data from one class to another). By "ROM" I mean persistent storage

Comment: So it's not ROM, please update the question

Comment: I try very simple ```getSingleValueFromSql(valueId, objectId)``` 
same with set function.
so we can achieve low memory usage and access to rarely used data.

Answer (score 2):

In the application code, use virtual getters and setters of `Object`, so that you won't need to change it if you change the implementation of Object.

```
class Object {
public:
    virtual string getA() { return ""; }
    virtual void setA(const string&) {}

    virtual string getB() { return "";  };
    virtual void setB(const string&) {}
};
```

Then, implement concrete data fields in `PartialObject`, that inherits from `Object`:

```
class PartialObject {
public:
    PartialObject() : k(KeyValueStore::invalidKey()) {}
    virtual string getA() { return a;  }
    virtual void setA(const string& str) { a = str; }

protected:
    KeyValueStore::key k; // This is for persistency

private:
    string a;
};
```

And implement `FullObject`, with the rest of the data fields, and with persistency capabilities:

```
class FullObject : public PartialObject {
public:
    FullObject(const PartialObject& partial) {
        *this = partial; 
    }

    virtual string getB() { return b; };
    virtual void setB(const string& s) { b = s;  }

    // This function persists the full object, and returns a partial object, so that the full object can be deleted.
    PartialObject save(KeyValueStore& kvStore) {
        if (!KeyValueStore::isKeyValid(k))
            k = kvStore.generateNewKey();
        kvStore.setValue(k, serialize());
        return PartialObject(reinterpret_cast<PartialObject&>(*this));
    }

    void load(KeyValueStore& kvStore) {
        deseriaize(kvStore.getValue(k));
    }
private:
    string serialize() {
        // Here you should implement the code for serializing all fields, and return serialized data as string.
    }
    void deseriaize(const string& str) {
        // Here you should set "this" to the deserialized version of str.
    }
private: 
    string b;
};
```

The class `KeyValueStore` is the data access layer:

```
class KeyValueStore {
public:
    typedef unsigned long key;

    string getValue(unsigned long long key);
    void setValue(unsigned long long key, const string& value);

    static bool isKeyValid(key k) { return k > 0; }
    static key invalidKey() { return 0; }
    key generateNewKey();
};
```

Comment: this is kind of fat solution. I try very simple ```getSingleValueFromSql(valueId, objectId)```

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe not so useful to have the extension hold information on *what it is extending* rather than have the object itself hold a reference to its optional extension. But that design decision has apparently already been taken.

One simple way to do that is have the Object hold a private pointer to the extension and a public method to obtain this pointer. Then do lazy evaluation of that pointer only in case someone needs it.

```
class Object {
  private:
  string importantData;
  ObjectExtended *extension;

  public:
  ObjectExtended *getExtension () {
    if (extension == NULL) {
      // Load from file or database
      extension = loadFromFile (id);
    }
    return extension;
  }
```

You can even drive that further by making *getExtension()* private as well and adding public accessor methods for extension data to Object that call *getExtension* in turn. This would hide the presence or non-presence of the *extension* data in memory completely. In case memory gets tight, you can walk through the list of objects and delete extension pointers, thus freeing up memory.

Depending on the exact nature of your problem and memory considerations, it could be useful to hold additional information on last recently/most frequently used extension data in *Object*, so you can better decide *what exactly* to purge when memory gets tight.